# Testing code inside of a then() block

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, asynchronous, mocha.js

So I am using React and testing with Mocha/Chai/Enzyme/Sinon. I have a lot of asynchronous calls in my components and I want to test the code that comes after but can't figure out how.

So for example this is my reserveSession() method inside of my AddToCart component:

```
reserveSession() { 
  this.props.reserveExam(id).then((json) => {
    // Code I want to test 
   }).catch(...);
}
```

And here is the current setup of my test:

```
describe('AddToCartButton', () => {
  beforeEach(() => { 
    props = { 
      // set all props to empty or () => null 
    }
    wrapper = mount(<AddToCartButton {...props} />)
  }); 
});
```

So what I have found so far is that when I mock this.props.reserveExam in the before each, since it doesn't ever call the actual function, it never calls the code in the then, but if i just call the method it doesn't understand what the then is. Any ideas on how to test this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's written it's very difficult to isolate your `then` handler in a unit test.  As you can see, having to go directly through the promise api to indirectly call your code is a pain.  As you project grows and the promise becomes more complicated maintenance cost will continue to increase.

What if you were trying to test step 5 of your promise chain?? You'd have to stub out all handlers before the 5th step??

A more isolated test could be created by defining the handler outside of your promise chain:

```
var iExist = (json) => {
    dostuff();
}

reserveSession() { 
  this.props.reserveExam(id).then(
     iExist
  ).catch(...);
}
```

Now look how trivial it is to test your method directly!!!

---

Of course at some level it will be good to exercise your promise code.  But it should only need 1 or two tests to make sure everything's wired up correctly, or you could do it indirectly as part of an end-to-end/functional test.

Comment: This a very good note, and since we are building the project right now it would be a good time to do this. I think cshion answers my problem for the short term but this is definitely the long term fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with stubs, you could stub a property of variable 'props' so when call function reserveExam, you force to return a promise with json_data resolved.

```
let json_data = {..custom data};
let stubed = sinon.stub(props,'reserveExam').callsFake(function(){
    return Promise.resolve(json_data);
});
```